# Is it possible to use Process() to launch tools from /usr/libexec?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm working on a small macOS application which is basically a launcher for a Java based tool. I need to determine if the correct version of Java is installed on the host system. I tried using the `java_home` tool by doing something like this:

```
func checkJavaVersion(version: String) -> Bool {
    let process = Process()
    process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/libexec/java_home")
    process.arguments = ["-F", "-v \(version)"]
    process.launch()
    process.waitUntilExit()
    return true; // For now...
}
```

But this fails with a `launch path not accessible` error. If I understand correctly, this is because the application isn't allowed to launch utilities located outside of `/usr/bin`.

Is there any way around this, or does anyone know a better way to detect if a specific Java version is installed from inside a Swift application?

Comment: Is your app sandboxed? That's usually the issue, because it prevents your program from launching other arbitrary programs

Comment: Yes, it's sandboxed. Without the sandboxing capability the above code works. I thought that was required to notarise the app, but now that I read again I see that only hardened runtime seems to be required. That being said, I would prefer a way where the sandbox can be retained, but maybe it's not feasible.

Comment: The best you can do is add an unboxed XPC service to your sandboxed app, and have that do the work. "Principle of least privilege", and whatnot